# Customer Import - Welcome Email

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, import

I have around 1500 customers which I need to import into Magento from another CMS. The passwords in the old CMS are hashed therefore we have no idea of what they are.

Does anyone know of a way or an extension that will allow me to import the 1500 customer and also email them all to set a new password. Please note I dont want new passwords to be emailed to customers as this is bad practice. The ideal solution would be the customer would get an email with a link to click and then they enter their own new password on the site

Answer (score 0):

Magento has a fallback to MD5, so if the old CMS is using MD5 you can just import them and it works.

You can implement the hashing algorithm the old CMS is using, have a look here: https://github.com/ikonoshirt/pbkdf2/ how to change the Encryption model.

Beside this I recommend to install https://github.com/ikonoshirt/pbkdf2/ to have a hardened hashing algorithm instead of the badly `md5` used by magento